# arrange active record results against an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have array of active record objects that I want to sort in a particular order.

There could be 0 - 5 results:

```
[#<Milestone id: 657708, event_id: 2426, event_type: "Part", data_type: "setup_required", date_at: "2014-11-13 06:27:05", user_id: 1003>, #<Milestone id: 657707, event_id: 2426, event_type: "Part", data_type: "setup_ready", date_at: "2014-11-13 06:27:05", user_id: 1003>]
```

This is the array of the that I want to sort it by.

```
status = %w[setup_ready setup_required bom_processing pending_approval part_live]
```

I want to sort data_type against the elements of the array.

so in this case, my results would be this:

```
[#<Milestone id: 657707, event_id: 2426, event_type: "Part", data_type: "setup_ready", date_at: "2014-11-13 06:27:05", user_id: 1003>, #<Milestone id: 657708, event_id: 2426, event_type: "Part", data_type: "setup_required", date_at: "2014-11-13 06:27:05", user_id: 1003>]
```

Code after suggestion:

```
milestones = Milestone.where(event_id: params[:id])
status = %w[setup_ready setup_required bom_processing pending_approval part_live]
@part_milestones = milestones.sort_by {|m| status.index(m.data_type)}

milestones = [#<Milestone id: 657708, event_id: 2426, event_type: "Part", data_type: "setup_required", date_at: "2014-11-13 06:27:05", user_id: 1003>, #<Milestone id: 657707, event_id: 2426, event_type: "Part", data_type: "setup_ready", date_at: "2014-11-13 06:27:05", user_id: 1003>]

@part_milestones = [#<Milestone id: 657708, event_id: 2426, event_type: "Part", data_type: "setup_required", date_at: "2014-11-13 06:27:05", user_id: 1003>, #<Milestone id: 657707, event_id: 2426, event_type: "Part", data_type: "setup_ready", date_at: "2014-11-13 06:27:05", user_id: 1003>]
```

Solved by adding to_s:

@part_milestones = milestones.sort_by {|m| status.index(m.data_type.to_s)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `milestones` contains the collection of Milestone ActiveRecord objects:

```
milestones = Milestone.all
status = %w[setup_ready setup_required bom_processing pending_approval part_live]

sorted_milestones = milestones.sort_by {|m| status.index(m.data_type)}
```

If there are any milestone data_types that do not exist in the status list, they should get sorted to the end of the array.

Comment: hmm, this is seems like it should work. There are no errors, but it's not changing the order. I will put it above.

Comment: Either assign to a new variable or use `sort_by!` if you want to change the existing `milestones` collection.

Comment: I tried the bang, but no luck. I may try again since the solution I posted above I don't feel is ideal. Thanks for the help!